# I am facing problem in creating a Graph implementation

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph

**The code is only accepting 2 values even though I am providing limit (n-variable) other than 2.**
**I am not able to understand what's going wrong in `Graph()`**

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

class Node
{
private:
      int data;
      Node *next;
      friend class Graph;
};

class Graph
{
private:
      Node *head[20];
      int n;
public:
      Graph();
      void insert_node(Node *head);
      void insert_vertices(Node *ver);
};
Graph :: Graph()
{
      cout<<"\nEnter Number of Nodes:";
      cin>>n;
      head[n] = new Node();
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
            cout<<"\nEnter The Head_node:";
            cin>>head[i]->data;
            head[i]->next = NULL;
      }
}
int main() {
      Graph g;
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not initializing most of the Nodes before you try to set their data.  You're trying to use the pointers without making them actually point at anything first.  You can fix this by initializing the Nodes in the loop.  Here's an updated version of your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout << "\nEnter The Head_node:";
    head[i] = new Node();
    cin >> head[i]->data;
    head[i]->next = NULL;
}
```